# Angular2 Observable not get called if there is access to result attribute

Tags: angular, observable

I have an HTTP service like this to retrieve a user list:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private _dataStore: {
         users: User[]
    };
    private _users: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>();
    public usersObservable: Observable<User[]> = this._users.asObservable();

    ...

    public list(): void {
    this
        .http
        .get('/users')
        .subscribe((res) => {
            this._dataStore.users = res.json() as User[];
            this._users.next(Object.assign({}, this._dataStore).users);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my component:

```
export class UsersComponent {
    public users: User[] = [];
    private usersObservable: Observable<User[]>;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.usersObservable = this.userService.usersObservable;
    }

    public listUsers(): void {
        this.usersObservable.subscribe(data => {
            this.users = data;
            console.log(this.users.length); // <- this line cause the mysterious bug, 
            // a replace with console.log(this.users) makes the app works correctly
        }));
        this.userService.list();
    }
}
```

And the view of this component is just a table with rows like

```
<tr *ngFor='let user of users'>
........ <!-- Display data here -->
</tr>
```

The problem is, if I call any function that access to the attributes of data or this.users, the observable won't get called. If I just console.log(this.users) or console.log(data), everything went fine.

Do you have any idea where the problem is ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doing 2 async operations but you are mixing them up.

First you subscribe to `usersObservable` which is initially just a `BehaviorSubject` with no value.

Then you call the async `list()` method to fill up your `Subject` so that your observable can have values.

Before your observable receive its values you are trying to display the length of the values which it doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

echonax is right, not sure why someone Downvoted it.

Just to clarify a bit: When you set up a `BehaviorSubject`, you have to set a default value, that will be yielded as soon as someone subscribes to it.
If you look on your code, you are subscribing to the subject (`this.usersObservable.subscribe(...`) Before even sending the call (`this.userService.list();`), so there's no way the BehaviorSubject will contain the value you want. If you replace that `BehaviorSubject` for a `ReplaySubject` it may solve your problem.

Now the "bug" you mention is a side effect of this and the nature of the debugger. When you `console.log(this.users.length)`, the console just prints a number as a result, i.e. 0. When `this.users` is populated, this number on the debugger won't change, because it's just a number.
However, `console.log(this.users)` prints a reference to this object, so it can be explored (those little arrows to see the contents), so when it gets populated, that's immediately after, you can see those changes in the debugger.
Try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users))` and you will see how by the time it logs the object it will be an empty array (because as it's a string, it doesn't update when the object updates)

Also, avoid using Subjects. Your solution can be probably improved by `publish()`ing the source. Take a look on this post for more insight: http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the downvoter is a "hate" downvoter. If you look up my activities, I've been downvoted 10 times in the same minute lol.

Comment: @echonax Thank you very much. It took me time to understand echonax's answer (which is well structured) but when things arrive, I found out that you did explain exactly where the problem was.

Comment: @olivarra1 Thank you for your explication very detailed.